# How do you make a animation toggle on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I want to make a Animation toggle when I hover over a certain div, and currently it starts but does not stop. Can someone look over my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  function loopAnimate(x, y) {
    $(x)
      .animate({
        top: "1px",
        left: "1px",
        height: "290px",
        width: "290px"
      }, y / 1.5)
      .animate({
        top: "-=104px",
        left: "-=104px",
        height: "500px",
        width: "500px"
      }, y, function() {
        loopAnimate(x, y);
      })
  }
 
 function loopStop(x) {
    $(x).stop();
  
 $(x)
      .css({
        top: "1px",
        left: "1px",
        height: "290px",
        width: "290px"
      });
  }
 
 
 $('#button').hover(function() {
  loopAnimate('.circle1', 1600)
  loopAnimate('.circle2', 1700)
  loopAnimate('.circle3', 1800)
 }, function() {
  loopStop('.circle1')
  loopStop('.circle2')
  loopStop('.circle3')
 })
 
 $('.wrapper').css('top', $(window).height() / 2 - 150);
 $('.wrapper').css('left', $(window).width() / 2 - 150);
 

})
```

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: gray;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
 width: 0;
 position: relative;
}

.circle1 {
 z-index: -1000;
 position: absolute;
 top: 1px;
 left: 1px;
 height: 290px;
 width: 290px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 4px #eee solid;
 border-radius: 100000000px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.circle2 {
 z-index: -1000;
 position: absolute;
 top: 1px;
 left: 1px;
 height: 290px;
 width: 290px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 4px #eee solid;
 border-radius: 100000000px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.circle3 {
 z-index: -1000;
 position: absolute;
 top: 1px;
 left: 1px;
 height: 290px;
 width: 290px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 4px #eee solid;
 border-radius: 100000000px;
 display: inline-block;
}

#button {
 position: relative;
 background: black;
 border-radius: 1000px;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 transition: 0.33s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
 <div class="circle1"></div>
 <div class="circle2"></div>
 <div class="circle3"></div>
 <div id='button'></div>
</div>
```

I mostly want it to smoothly stop abrupt. I really hope someone can help me.

EDIT: Solved. Changed loopStop too

function loopStop(x) {
    $(x).stop(true, false);

```
$(x)
  .animate({
    top: "1px",
    left: "1px",
    height: "290px",
    width: "290px"
  });
```

}

Comment: I only see one cirlcle. where's the other two

Comment: sorry . got that just now

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
 
  function loopAnimate(x, y) {
    $(x)
      .animate({
        top: "1px",
        left: "1px",
        height: "290px",
        width: "290px"
      }, y / 1.5)
      .animate({
        top: "-=104px",
        left: "-=104px",
        height: "500px",
        width: "500px"
      }, y, function() {
        loopAnimate(x, y);
      })
  }
 
 function loopStop(x) {
    x="."+x;
    $(x).stop(true,false);  
   $(x).css({
   top: "1px",
   left: "1px",
   height: "290px",
   width: "290px"
   });
  } 
 
 $('#button').mouseenter(function() {
  loopAnimate('.circle1', 1600)
  loopAnimate('.circle2', 1700)
  loopAnimate('.circle3', 1800)
 });
 $('#button').mouseleave(function() {
  loopStop('circle1')
  loopStop('circle2')
  loopStop('circle3')
 });
 
 $('.wrapper').css('top', $(window).height() / 2 - 150);
 $('.wrapper').css('left', $(window).width() / 2 - 150);
 

});
```

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: gray;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
 width: 0;
 position: relative;
}

.circle1 {
 z-index: -1000;
 position: absolute;
 top: 1px;
 left: 1px;
 height: 290px;
 width: 290px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 4px #eee solid;
 border-radius: 100000000px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.circle2 {
 z-index: -1000;
 position: absolute;
 top: 1px;
 left: 1px;
 height: 290px;
 width: 290px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 4px #eee solid;
 border-radius: 100000000px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.circle3 {
 z-index: -1000;
 position: absolute;
 top: 1px;
 left: 1px;
 height: 290px;
 width: 290px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 4px #eee solid;
 border-radius: 100000000px;
 display: inline-block;
}

#button {
 position: relative;
 background: black;
 border-radius: 1000px;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 transition: 0.33s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
 <div class="circle1"></div>
 <div class="circle2"></div>
 <div class="circle3"></div>
 <div id='button'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're calling `loopAnimate(x, y);` inside itself as a callback, just remove it

```
function loopAnimate(x, y) {
    $(x)
      .animate({
        top: "1px",
        left: "1px",
        height: "290px",
        width: "290px"
      }, y / 1.5)
      .animate({
        top: "-=104px",
        left: "-=104px",
        height: "500px",
        width: "500px"
      }, y)
  }
```

Comment: While my mouse is on the button i want it to run the animation still. I just want once my mouse moves for the animation to stop.

Comment: oh i miss understood you, sorry, try `$(x).stop(true, true)` or `$(x).finish()`

Comment: Just figured it out

Comment: I changed my loopStop to this: function loopStop(x) {
    $(x).stop(true, false);
  
 $(x)
      .animate({
        top: "1px",
        left: "1px",
        height: "290px",
        width: "290px"
      });
  }

Comment: good :) happy to give you a hint , unfortunately you can't mark my answer as a good one since it's not :/